# Convergence of $\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{x-x^2}\ln(1-x)}{\sin{\pi x^2}} \mathrm{d}x.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I would like to prove the convergence of the Newton integral

$$\int_0^1 f(x)\mathrm{d}x =\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{x-x^2}\ln(1-x)}{\sin{\pi x^2}} \mathrm{d}x.$$

I split this into two integrals $\displaystyle\int_0^\epsilon f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ and $\displaystyle\int_\epsilon^1 f(x)\mathrm{d}x$. It is easy to show that the integral is convergent on $(0, \epsilon]$ by limit comparison with $\displaystyle\int_0^\epsilon \frac{\sqrt{x}x}{\pi x^2}\mathrm{d}x$.

But I cannot find anything to compare with around $x = 1$ on $[\epsilon, 1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write $x = 1 - \delta$, you obtain

$$\int_0^{1-\varepsilon} \frac{\sqrt{(1-\delta)(1-(1-\delta))}\,\ln \delta}{\sin \bigl(\pi(1-\delta)^2\bigr)}\, d\delta = \int_0^{1-\varepsilon} \frac{\sqrt{\delta(1-\delta)}\,\ln \delta}{\sin \bigl(\pi(2\delta-\delta^2)\bigr)}\,d\delta,$$

and the integrand of that can be compared to the harmless

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}\,\ln x}{2\pi x}.$$

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it. From now on, I will strictly refer to simple mathematical objects as to "harmless" ones.

Comment: Thanks, @Did. Better that way round, less room for misunderstanding.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, what you propose is substituting the troublesome $1 - x = \delta$. The interval of integration changes accordingly. (I assume that $\mathrm{d}x = -\mathrm{d}\delta$, where did the $-1$ go?) Then you compare the obtained integral to an expression containing the original variable $x$ again; shall I substitute here, too? I assume this is an obvious step which I am not yet familiar with.

Comment: Exactly. And a nice solution, if you ask me. (I usually post a comment saying "if you do not like the modifications, just reverse them" but in this case, for some reason it seems I forgot.)

Comment: @DavidČepelík The $-1$ went into the change of order of integration boundaries, $\int_\varepsilon^1 dx\leadsto\int_{1-\varepsilon}^0d(1-\delta)\leadsto \int_0^{1-\varepsilon}d\delta$. The $x$ in the function to compare to is a generic variable, you can also call it $y$, $\text{Fred}$, or $\delta$.

Comment: So I assume this is setup for *comparison test*, not *limit comparison test*, correct? I assumed the latter for no reason. I think I am going to stick with $\mbox{Fred}$.

Comment: @DavidČepelík Frankly, I don't know what you youngins call "limit comparison test" or "comparison test". All I know is that if you can bound the absolute value of an integrand $f$ from above by an integrable function, then $f$ is (locally) integrable, if I can bound it from below by a non-integrable (non-negative) function, it's not locally integrable. If it's not locally integrable, a principal value may still exist.

Comment: The approach you propose we (youngins) call the *comparison test*. The other approach you surely know is to take the limit $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\mathrm{d}x$ where $f(x)$ is the given function, $g(x)$ the function you compare it with and $a \in \mathbb{R}^*$ is the "improper point" that is causing the trouble ($f(x)$ is not defined here or is discontinuous at this point). If the limit falls into $(0, \infty)$, then $\int f(x)$ is convergent when $\int g(x)$ is convergent. Moreover, you need both $f$ and $g$ to be continuous at the other end of the interval you integrate on.

Comment: Listening to what I wrote, it is the same as the *comparison test*, except with a finite amount of exceptions and with an arbitrary multiplicative constant $C \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @DavidČepelík Ah, but (supposing positive $f,g$), $\limsup\limits_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < \infty$ if and only if I can bound $f$ from above by $c\cdot g$, and $\liminf\limits_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} > 0$ if and only if I can bound $f$ from below by $c\cdot g$. So the limit comparison test is directly subsumed by ordinary comparison.

Comment: One last thing that confuses me. You establish the upper bound of the numerator to be $\sqrt{t}\ln\delta$ (so I assume we look for the upper bound of the whole function). Then you use that $(2\delta - \delta^2) \ge \delta$ on $(0, 1-\epsilon)$ and $\sin(x+\pi) = -\sin x$, so the argument of sine changes to $\sin 2\pi t$. As $\sin x$ grows on $(0, {\pi\over2})$, this lowers the value of the denominator. Okay. But then you replace the whole sine by its argument, which is greater. What am I missing?

Comment: What I actually did, @DavidČepelík, was to take an asymptotically equal function, not an upper or lower bound. So I guess my idea was the limit comparison test after all.

Comment: Perfect solution with only one serious imperfection - did not find it myself. Thanks for immense patience. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

Regarding to Quotient test for integrals with non-negative integrands, we have $$\lim_{x\to 1^-}{(1-x)^{0.6}|f(x)|}=0<\infty$$ so the integral $$\int_{\epsilon>0}^1|f(x)|dx$$ converges