# Convergence of $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\sqrt{x-x^2}}{\sin(\pi x)} \, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have difficulties with convergence of this integral:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x) \sqrt{x-x^2}}{\sin(\pi x)} \, dx$$
I found similar problem here [Covergence of integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488299/convergence-of-int-01-frac-sqrtx-x2-ln1-x-sin-pi-x2-mathrmdx) but I don't get the solution from there.

I split the interval on two intervals: $(0,\alpha]$ and $[\alpha,1)$. The integral on the first interval convergs following a limit comparison test with $\frac{x^{3/2}}{\pi x}$.

But I am struggling with the second interval. Can somebody show me what to do on the second interval $[\alpha,1)$?

Answer (score -1):

For $x$ close to $1$ the integrand

$$ \frac{\ln(1-x)\sqrt{x-x^3}}{\sin \pi x} \sim c\frac{\ln(1-x)}{\sqrt{x-1}} $$

which is an integrable function

Comment: Under the radical, it is $\, x-x^{\color{red}2}$.

Comment: @Bernard: No, it as I posted it.

Comment: Well, I was referring to @GorteX's post.

Comment: @Bernard is true..can you (science) add more to your answer?